# Provide configuration interface in managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have a managed package that will be distributed publicly, I want to build a custom interface that allows users to modify some default settings that will be stored in their org. These settings will be referenced by both apex code and external applications.

I'm assuming for this I'll need to write a custom lightning component using aura/LWC? Or do I need a lightning page? I've look briefly into lightning apps, and I'm wondering how this comes into play as well.

Comment: Also please share if you have any advice in choosing between aura/LWC for someone with no experience with either

Comment: Assume the settings itself will be in custom settings or custom metadata... You can provide aura/lwc/visualforce for changing them or manage it from salesforce setup. It depend on the complexity of the settings and who going to manage it.